# Using regex to replace an entire column in Pandas.

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, I've looked through the other questions on this topic, and all of them either do not work for my case, or maybe I'm just not understanding them.  I have a dataframe in pandas that has about 8 columns.  The 8th column is the one where I want to use regular expression to extract a certain portion from each element of that column.  The code that I have seen to do this is the following:

```
new[8].replace(r'.*', r'Name=.*;', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

So, I thought in this code, the first part is the pattern you want to replace, (that's why I'm using the .* expression to match everything."  I thought the second part is the pattern you want to extract (in my case, I want to use the Name=.*; regular expression pattern.)  What ends up happening, is it just replaces everything in the column with exactly the second text I provide.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you add some sample input and output?

Comment: If you want to use the regex match info for your replacement, you need to write a function that takes a regex match object and returns the string that you'd like to replace with. Then you can pass that function in as an argument to `replace` and get the behavior you're looking for (if the nonregex solution doesn't work for whatever reason)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for pointing this out.  I'll go ahead and create this function!

Answer (score 3):

You may not need regex in this case, try

```
new[8] = 'Name=' + new[8].astype(str)
```